# Reinstall a patch with composer - update one module only

Tags: 8, composer

Can I update a patch without running `composer update` ? In other words: can I update one module only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use the following:

```
composer update --prefer-source drupal/menu_block
```